Why is typescript added as a Peer Dependency in solana web3js repos?
A lot if not all the repos in https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/tree/master/packages have this in their package.js
"peerDependencies": {
"typescript": ">=5"
},
Is there a reason why it as to be a peerDependency and not a devDependency, peer dependencies seems to not be affected by the --prod flag in yarn and npm prune so it ends up bloating the production build. Am I missing something?, thanks!

This PR describes why the change was made: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/pull/2576
Quoting from there:

I'm seeing quite a few people struggle with type errors in Technology Preview 3. We need to telegraph, through package.json that this package requires TypeScript 5 or higher. This is mostly due to our use of const type parameters, which were introduced in TypeScript 5.


I see, that makes sense, I'm wondering what's the best approach to remove those dev dependencies then.

I faced the same issue after including @solana/spl-token dependency.
It causes build failure with this type error message:

Type error: Type parameter declaration expected.


To overcome this, set correct devDependencies version in package.json of your project.

"typescript": "~5.4.2"

Then go with yarn install and yarn build again.
